# How can i make faster container starting for vscode dev containers?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have a good machine for developing inside containers, but containers starting take at least one minute, how can i make it faster?

Also can i have common extensions kit for any next dev container? Because i have to click "Install in Dev container..." button on every needed extension in my new dev container now.

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: @Evert yep, but by the way this dockerfile generated by vscode
https://gist.github.com/EternalWinter/68f764094f8fdc729e6f4189433d1b37

Comment: There's nothing here that should make *running* the container slow, because nothing actually gets run. All the statements in there are during build. Can you just cache this build?

Comment: How can i do that? Every time when i run vscode with project inside it's start cloning the repo and building the project, i found nothing inside documentation about dev containers for that